# Setting tile on download document does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to set file download on link,
but I'm not able to set desired title of document, It takes default name as **document.pdf**
Here is [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srjahir32/zvuwsudj/).

HTML

```
<a id='dwnldLnk'  onclick="downloadPDF();">fdfdfd </a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
window.downloadPDF = function downloadPDF() {
    var dlnk = document.getElementById('dwnldLnk');
    dlnk.href = pdf;
    dlnk.download = "abc.pdf";
    dlink.click(); 
}
var pdf = "http://fortress-api-dev.herokuapp.com/api/documents/4015fbba21c84c0d83409565662887fe";
```

Comment: Server set `Content-Disposition` header so you cannot do it client side because `download` attribute is ignored regarding spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: @A.Wolff You mean to Title should be set in header of that URL response ?

Comment: If by title you mean file name, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the attribute **download** to define a new filename, it must have an extension file.
But, you could set the media_type, in your case, use **application/pdf**:

```
window.downloadPDF = function downloadPDF() {
var dlnk = document.getElementById('dwnldLnk');
var media_type_pdf = "data:application/pdf;"
dlnk.href = `${media_type_pdf}${pdf}`;
dlnk.download = "abc.pdf";
//dlink.click(); 
}
var pdf = "http://fortress-api-dev.herokuapp.com/api/documents/4015fbba21c84c0d83409565662887fe";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fileType = ('data:application/vnd.ms-'+type);
   //type can be pdf,csv,xls......
         extension ='xls';
         fileName = ( name+"." + extension );
         blob = new Blob( [ file ], { type: fileType } );
         //file is your content
         url = window.URL.createObjectURL( blob );
         a = document.createElement( "a" );
         // Set link on DOM.
         document.body.appendChild( a );
         // Set link's visibility.
         a.style = "display: none";
         // Set href on link.
         a.href = url;
         // Set file name on link.
         a.download = fileName;
         // Trigger click of link.
         a.click();
```